# Continue developing an already installed application

Tags: python, linux, deployment

I recently wrote my first setup.py (with distutils) for an application I'm working on. This installed the library in /usr/local/lib/python and the executable script in /usr/local/bin. This is great, except I want to continue working on it, and whenever I call my application it first looks in /usr/local and runs it from there, instead of the directory I'm at. So I have to manually go and delete the files form these locations. What is the proper way to do this?

Comment: Use `./app` instead of `app`? How are you calling it?

Comment: @Blender -- Typically, this will still use the installed library rather than your local one.

Comment: @Blender I just do "python app_name", but it takes all the imports from /usr/local/lib unless I manually remove them.

Comment: @Diana -- did you try to set the `PYTHONPATH` environment variable to include the directory where you do your development?  This only works if your module is pure python (no C extensions).

Comment: @mgilson -- No, I haven't changed the environment variable. Wouldn't that ruin it for the installed script when I actually want to call the one in /usr/local?

Comment: I tried adding it to the environment variable, and it has an issue with the module path (the first package name). Not sure if this is because I've done some unconventional naming and importing. I ended up writing a small shell script that will run `python setup.py build`, `python setup.py install` and then call my app `my_app $1`. I'm just running that every time I change something, and it's very convenient. I'm quite sure this is not the proper way to do it though. I'd still be interested in what I _should_ have done, if anyone has any ideas. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you've got it all packaged up you should be able to say

```
python setup.py develop
```

and it will install it locally for you to test.

Then, if you want to uninstall it just

```
pip uninstall my_package
```